# Intellij Grails and Git

Tags: git, grails, intellij-idea

I want to backup my code using smart Git. As a start I am a bit confused, IntelliJ has created two folders for my Grails project:

1. `C:\Documents and Settings\me\.grails\1.2.1\projects`
2. `C:\Documents and Settings\me\IdeaProjects\`

#1 contains a plugins folder containing directories and files of plugins I am using inside my project.

The question is: **Do I have to include both #1 and #2 directories inside GIT?**

If yes, what can I ignore?

If no, which of the files do I have to include?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stuff under the .grails folder shouldn't be version-controlled. That's where classes are compiled, temp files are created, etc. Also plugins get installed there but typically you don't want to check those in since they're derived.

Another developer who checks out your code will have the plugins listed in application.properties and when running for the first time Grails will detect that they're not installed and install them.

As for your project code, most files that you wouldn't want to check in are now created in the target directory, so that should be in your git ignore but most everything else other than log files should be checked in.

Comment: Burt,
This is how my .gitignore looks like  

*.iws  
*.iml  
*.ipr  
*.log  
lib  
obj  
bin  
.idea  
.classpath  
.project  
.settings  
.classpath  
/*.launch  
/*.tmproj  
  
# web application files that are overwritten by "grails upgrade"  
#  cf. GRAILS_HOME/scripts/Upgrade.groovy, target( upgrade )  
/web-app/WEB-INF  
  
# logs  
stacktrace.log  
/test/reports  
  
# project release file  
*.war

Comment: You should probably not exclude IDE files (.classpath, .project, the IntelliJ stuff, etc.), otherwise other developers will have to re-create those.

Comment: Yes Burt I agree but I am the only one working on this project, so that should be fine?

Comment: Sure. I'd still check them in though to avoid having to recreate them if you lose them, but it's not a big deal either way.